# Single <br /> doesn't create a line break instead, requires two

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a Wordpress theme and have been using Bootstrap a bit. I put my article excerpt for the homepage in a well, `div class='well'`. I have edited the well to have straight corners and have changed the border colour. Except those, there aren't any changes. 
But, when I try to add a linebreak between categories and tags, it doesn't float to extreme left as in the image below.

Q1. How to use a single `<br />` to make a line break between the two?
Q2. There's a lot of blank space in the well after the category and tags. How to remove it?

**HTML Code**

```
<div class="categories"><?php the_category(' '); ?></div><br /><br /><div class="tags"><?php the_tags('',' '); ?></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.categories{float:left; margin-right:3px;margin-bottom: 1px;}
.categories a {
background: #00A1E0;
color: #FFFFFF;
display: inline-block;
margin-bottom: 2px;
margin-left: 0px;
padding: 1px 7px;
text-decoration: none;
transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
} 
.categories a:hover{background:  #666; color:#fff;}

.tags{float:left; margin-right:1%;margin-bottom:4px;}
.tags a {
font-size:70%;
background:#666666;
color: #FFFFFF;
display: inline-block;
margin-bottom: 3px;
margin-left: 0px;
padding: 1px 7px;
text-decoration: none;
transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
} 
.tags a:hover{color:#FFFFFF;}
```

**When I use single `<br />`, this is what happens**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIDYt.png (Sorry, can't post images due to lack of rep).

Comment: To be honest, you shouldn't be using `br` for **element** spacing...that's what margins / padding are for.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove float style. Use only display: inline-block. Or use clear: both for first tag after div.

Comment: When I do that the tags does come down. But, this is what happens on desktop - the edit button comes down too -http://i.imgur.com/AJhGMb7.png which just creates more white space below which I am trynna remove.

Comment: Use two block containers (div) for categories and tag. So they will be just one below the other. Lay these containers inline-block elements

Comment: I added the float style back and added clea instead of clear:both. Now, its almost fixed, except the whitespace formed below.