# after <text>, in cshtml, single <br /> does not give line break

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Though slightly different, this question [does not seem to be new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30136090/single-br-doesnt-create-a-line-break-instead-requires-two), yet the only answer given in the link is rather short and not as explaining.

I am creating an ASP.NET MVC web App and in one of my `cshtml` file I have the following lines:

```
<text>@Html.ActionLink("Create New Employee", "Create")</text>
<br />
something else below
```

Although I already put a line break, the result is the same with if I do not put any `<br />`, both will be rendered into the following result:

[image]

Notice that "Mark" is directly put after "Create New Employee". And the result is identical with when I only put

```
<text>@Html.ActionLink("Create New Employee", "Create")</text>
no break here
something else below
```

without `<br/>`

Only when I put double `<br />` then it will be rendered with extra line break:

```
<text>@Html.ActionLink("Create New Employee", "Create")</text>
<br />
<br />
something else
```

resulting in:

[image]

Now, I am not pretty new to web app making, thus there might be some special properties of `<br/>` tag which I am not aware of. When I used `<br/>` after `<h4>` or `<table>` it seems fine. But why when I put after `<text>`, before `<ul>`, it cannot be rendered as I expected? Is this common issue to put two `<br/>` instead of one?

Comment: Why are you putting it inside `<text>` tags? And why not just style the `<ul>` tag with padding or margins?

Comment: @StephenMuecke You mean, the `ActionLink`? To be honest, I am not so familiar with the common practice for web project as I am new to the web app. But borrowing from my past non-web programming experience, typically I would assign something by an object which would best represent what I intend to. So, I thought since "Create New Employee" should be the text above a list of employees, I use `<text>` for it and `<ul>` for the list of employees. But I am open if you want to give me your opinions or corrections regarding the my practice... I am unaware if it is deemed as bad practice.

Comment: first of all why are you using `@Html.Action()` inside `<text></text>`

Comment: `<br/>` is a HTML line break, so in your example above this will add a single line break after your `<text/>` element, so your HTML is performing as designed, as @StephenMuecke states in his comment you would be better using a `<ul>` element and styling to get your desired result, something like (and excuse syntax) `li:first { margin-top: 12px; }`

Comment: @Neil ok, thanks for all the inputs. If that is a more common practice, I would gladly just use `<li>` to do that. That aside, if `<br/>` be the HTML line break, why would the result for `<text></text><ul></ul>` without `<br/>` and `<text></text><br/><ul></ul>` be the same? does `<ul>` or `<text>` have inherent **conditional** `<br/>` before or after its tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `something else below` in your code stands for unordered list (`ul`) with some list items (`li`), so I guess your generated HTML looks something like this:

```
<a href="#">Create New Employee</a>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Mark</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Luke</a></li>
</ul>
```

Let's investigate what is going on. `a` is inline element. As described in [this article](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp):

> An inline element does not start on a new line and only takes up as
>   much width as necessary.

`ul` element on the other hand is block-level element, and as described in the same article

> A block-level element always starts on a new line and takes up the
>   full width available (stretches out to the left and right as far as it
>   can).

So based on description above, `ul` always starts from the new line. If you don't add `br` after `a`, then `ul` is moved to next line automatically. If you add `br`, then there is no need to move `ul` to a new line because it is already there.

So overall - a line break before `ul` seems to be ignored, because `ul` is block-level element and it is displayed on the new line.

I created [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p1ks4zxh/) with visible element borders, so it is clearer to see what is going on.

Comment: I see... So, it is due to the `<ul>`.. not the `<text>` thanks for the article and the clarification.